# Apache Fuseki data set erroe in sparql INSERT

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, fuseki

i'm trying to do a sparql insert for an ontology application into a dataset created with a owl file
I'm using Apache Jena from Java and fuseki for reasoner.
If i try to do the select

```
prefix eos-ontology-meets:<http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#> select ?x ?y {?p eos-ontology-meets:name "Mario" . ?p ?x ?y .}
```

it works fine but i have a problem with the insert that it looks like with a correct syntax

```
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#"> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX oo:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 

INSERT DATA
{
   owl:barilla2 rdf:type owl:company;
               rdf:type oo:NamedIndividual;
               owl:companyid 456 ; 
               owl:vatnumber 111111111111; 
               owl:address 'Test2 test2 test2' .
}
```

that send me back this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " <INSERT_DATA> "INSERT DATA "" at line 5, column 2.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "describe" ...
    "construct" ...
    "ask" ...
```

This is the owl file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/giuseppe/ontologies/2020/5/untitled-ontology-39#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/giuseppe/ontologies/2020/5/untitled-ontology-39"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:eos-ontology-meets="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#meets -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#meets"/>
    


<!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#address -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#address"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#companyid -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#companyid"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiscalcode -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiscalcode"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#gender -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#gender"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#name -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#name"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#personid -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#personid"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#surname -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#surname"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#telephone -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#telephone"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#vatnumber -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#vatnumber"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#company -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#company">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#registry"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#person -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#person">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#registry"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#registry -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#registry"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#barilla -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#barilla">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#company"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#mariorossi"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#transportsrl"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Via Firenze 5</eos-ontology-meets:address>
        <eos-ontology-meets:companyid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">102</eos-ontology-meets:companyid>
        <eos-ontology-meets:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Barilla</eos-ontology-meets:name>
        <eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">7894654132</eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiat -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiat">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#company"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#luigiverdi"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#transportsrl"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Via Vienna 78</eos-ontology-meets:address>
        <eos-ontology-meets:companyid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">100</eos-ontology-meets:companyid>
        <eos-ontology-meets:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Fiat</eos-ontology-meets:name>
        <eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">45456465</eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#luigiverdi -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#luigiverdi">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#person"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiat"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#mariorossi"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Via trieste 15</eos-ontology-meets:address>
        <eos-ontology-meets:fiscalcode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LLLCCCFFF123456</eos-ontology-meets:fiscalcode>
        <eos-ontology-meets:gender rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">M</eos-ontology-meets:gender>
        <eos-ontology-meets:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Luigi</eos-ontology-meets:name>
        <eos-ontology-meets:personid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1</eos-ontology-meets:personid>
        <eos-ontology-meets:surname rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Verdi</eos-ontology-meets:surname>
        <eos-ontology-meets:telephone rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">123456789</eos-ontology-meets:telephone>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#mariorossi -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#mariorossi">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#person"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#barilla"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#luigiverdi"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Via Savona 23</eos-ontology-meets:address>
        <eos-ontology-meets:fiscalcode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TTTREWEDD456</eos-ontology-meets:fiscalcode>
        <eos-ontology-meets:gender rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">M</eos-ontology-meets:gender>
        <eos-ontology-meets:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Mario</eos-ontology-meets:name>
        <eos-ontology-meets:personid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">2</eos-ontology-meets:personid>
        <eos-ontology-meets:surname rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Rossi</eos-ontology-meets:surname>
        <eos-ontology-meets:telephone rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">789456132</eos-ontology-meets:telephone>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#transportsrl -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#transportsrl">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#company"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#barilla"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:meets rdf:resource="http://www.gruppomcr.com/2020/06/eos-ontology-meets#fiat"/>
        <eos-ontology-meets:address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Via Lucca 5</eos-ontology-meets:address>
        <eos-ontology-meets:companyid rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">101</eos-ontology-meets:companyid>
        <eos-ontology-meets:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Transport srl</eos-ontology-meets:name>
        <eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">7654325687435</eos-ontology-meets:vatnumber>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Comment: you are using the wrong service URL. For SPARQL update queries like `INSERT` it is supposed to be `update` and not `query`. Also maybe check https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-data-services.html , I guess this will help you